# Web Scraping using Beautifulsoup : need values one after the other

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

so I have been learning web Scrapping using python ,so whenever I try to scrape a data from a HTML file I do get the results but its all in a single line and its confusing. For example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

file=open('op.html','rb')
data=file.read()
soup=BeautifulSoup(data,'html.parser')
print(soup.select('style'))
```

so this the data which I want to scrape

output:

```
<style data-href="/styles.59fbc549822f5988841c.css" data-identity="gatsby-global-css">/*! @docsearch/css 3.2.1 | MIT License | © Algolia, Inc. and contributors | https://docsearch.algolia.com */:root{--docsearch-primary-color:#5468ff;--docsearch-text-color:#1c1e21;--docsearch-spacing:12px;--docsearch-icon-stroke-width:1.4;--docsearch-highlight-color:var(--docsearch-primary-color);--docsearch-muted-color:#969faf;--docsearch-container-background:rgba(101,108,133,.8);
```

what I want is that the result be Separated line by line so it will be clear to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Use `print(soup.select('style').prettify())`. It will give you a nicely formatted Unicode string, with a separate line for each tag and each string.

Comment: not working ...